# Помогите с задачей на паттерны проектирования на Java

Tags: java

Есть задача: Разработать класс Светофор, у которого должен быть метот next(), при вызове которого должна загораться текущая секция светофора. Но прикол в другом, надо решить ее без if, for, while, switch. Также обязательное условие: добавление секций возможно без переписывания класса Светофор.

Мой вариант без применения паттернов:

Светофор:

```
public class TrafficLight {
  List<ISection> section = new ArrayList<>();
  int index = 0;

  public void addSection(ISection section) {
    this.section.add(section);
  }

  public void next (){
    section.get(index++%section.size()).light();
  }
}
```

Секция светофора:

```
public class Section implements ISection{
 String color;

  public Section(String color) {
    this.color = color;
  }

  @Override
  public void light() {
    System.out.println(color);
  }
}
```

Решение рабочее, но в жизни желтый горит и после красного, и после зеленого, а у меня не так. Думаю что добавление 4-ой секции недопустимо, поэтому прошу помочь мне реализовать "правильный" светофор с соблюдением условий задачи и возможным применением какого-то паттерна поведения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это всё можно сделать классически через паттерн состояния.

```
public interface TrafficLight {

    void lightUp();

    void setState(LightState lightState);

}
```

```
public class TrafficLightImpl implements TrafficLight {

    private LightState currentState;

    public TrafficLightImpl(LightState startState) {
        this.currentState = startState;
    }

    @Override
    public void lightUp() {
        currentState.lightUp();
        currentState.goToNextState(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void setState(LightState lightState) {
        currentState = lightState;
    }
}
```

```
public enum LightState {

    GREEN("Зелёный") {
        @Override
        public void goToNextState(TrafficLight trafficLight) {
            trafficLight.setState(PRE_YELLOW);
        }
    },
    PRE_YELLOW("Жёлтый") {
        @Override
        public void goToNextState(TrafficLight trafficLight) {
            trafficLight.setState(RED);;
        }
    },
    RED("Красный") {
        @Override
        public void goToNextState(TrafficLight trafficLight) {
            trafficLight.setState(POST_YELLOW);;
        }
    },
    POST_YELLOW("Жёлтый") {
        @Override
        public void goToNextState(TrafficLight trafficLight) {
            trafficLight.setState(GREEN);;
        }
    },
    INFINITY_YELLOW("Мигающий жёлтый") {
        @Override
        public void goToNextState(TrafficLight trafficLight) {
            // no logic
        }
    };

    private final String color;

    LightState(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public abstract void goToNextState(TrafficLight trafficLight);

    public void lightUp() {
        System.out.println(color);
    }
}
```

Этот паттерн подразумевает то, что каждое состояние знает куда ему переходить дальше. То есть, если у нас сейчас зелёный, то программа должна понимать, что дальше - жёлтый.

В более сложных версиях у каждого состояния должен быть абстрактный метод не только `goToNextState()`, но и `lightUp()`, чтобы реализация поведения была разная (в моём случае нет необходимости). Хотя, если добавить ещё одно состояние OFF, то есть выключен, то при вызове метода `lightUp()` будет как раз нужно отдельное поведение, но это можно решить добавлением следующего состояния в `LightState`:

```
    OFF("") {
        @Override
        public void goToNextState(TrafficLight trafficLight) {
            // no logic
        }

        @Override
        public void lightUp() {
            System.out.println("Светофор выключен!");
        }
    };
```

Тестирование программы:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final TrafficLight trafficLight = new TrafficLightImpl(LightState.GREEN);

        trafficLight.lightUp(); // Зелёный
        trafficLight.lightUp(); // Жёлтый
        trafficLight.lightUp(); // Красный
        trafficLight.lightUp(); // Жёлтый
        trafficLight.lightUp(); // Зелёный
        trafficLight.lightUp(); // Жёлтый
        trafficLight.lightUp(); // Красный
        trafficLight.lightUp(); // Жёлтый
        trafficLight.lightUp(); // Зелёный
        trafficLight.setState(LightState.INFINITY_YELLOW);
        trafficLight.lightUp(); // Жёлтый
        trafficLight.lightUp(); // Жёлтый
        trafficLight.lightUp(); // Жёлтый
        trafficLight.lightUp(); // Жёлтый
    }
```

P.S. Я использовал `enum` для большей наглядности, чтобы на расписывать тут по сотни классов. В реальности можете сделать это не через `enum`, а просто через обычное наследование - ничего принципиально не измениться.

Answer (score 1):

Следует различать набор секций -- в простейшем случае 3 для обычного светофора -- и набор состояний этого светофора.

В частности, в заданном *состоянии* светофора может быть дополнительная информация, например длительность его горения, моргание и т.п.

И именно с *состояниями* светофора должен работать метод `next`, так как их проще сконфигурировать при "прямом" (от красного к зеленому) и "обратном" (от зеленого к красному) ходе.

Например, также просто "присвоить" светофору единственное состояние, например мигающий желтый.

```java
enum Light {
    RED, AMBER, GREEN,                   // основные цвета
    RED_GREEN_LEFT, RED_GREEN_RIGHT,     // доп. секции
    ;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name().toLowerCase();
    }
}

public class LightState {
    final Light light;
    boolean blink;
    int seconds;

    static LightState of(Light light, int sec) {
        return of(light, sec, false);
    }

    static LightState of(Light light, int sec, boolean blink) {
        return new LightState(light, sec, blink);
    }

    LightState(Light light, int sec, boolean blink) { 
        this.light = light;
        this.seconds = sec;
        this.blink = blink;
    }

    public void light() {
        System.out.printf("%s for %d sec%s%n", light, seconds, blink ? " blink" : "");
    }
}

public class TrafficLight {
    List<Light> lights;        // просто огни светофора
    List<LightState> states;   // состояния

    // конструктор

    int index = 0;

    public void next () {
        states.get(index++ % states.size()).light();
    }
}
```

Тест:

```java
TrafficLight basic = new TrafficLight(
    Arrays.asList(Light.RED, Light.AMBER, Light.GREEN),
    Arrays.asList(of(Light.RED, 45), of(Light.AMBER, 15), of(Light.GREEN, 40), of(Light.GREEN, 5, true), of(Light.AMBER, 15))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Решение 1**
Возможно стоит сделать массив `algorithm` и в методе `next` итерироваться по нему. А в элементах массива будут индексы элементов списка `section`.

**Решение 2**
Можно сделать нового наследника `ISection`, который будет указывать на другой ISection. Но так всё равно добавлять новый элемент в список.

Answer (score 0):

А чем итератор плох? Его просто нужно сделать циклическим, что в целом не сложно.

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public class TrafficLight {

    private final Iterator<Colors> iterator = new Sections(Colors.values()).iterator();

    public void next() {
        System.out.println(iterator.next());
    }
}

class Sections implements Iterable<Colors> {

    private final Colors[] colors;
    private int i;

    public Sections(Colors... colors) {
        this.i = 0;
        this.colors = colors;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Colors> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<Colors>() {
            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return true;
            }
            @Override
            public Colors next() {
                try {
                    return colors[i++];
                } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                    i = 0;
                    return colors[i++];
                }
            }
        };
    }
}

enum Colors {
    GREEN, YELLOW, RED;
}
```